# Updating inner HTML which changes every x seconds in pyscript?

Tags: javascript, python, infinite-loop, pyscript

I have a python script which reads data from a sensor, now I want to display those data in HTML page. I tried  `Element('id').write(value)`   inside a infinite loop but it also not working. is there any way to do this folks.

Comment: 1) Show the HTML code that **id** references. 2) Do not use infinite loops in the browser, You will hang the browser session and CPU usage will jump to 100%. 3) Browser-based applications **must** be event driven and not procedural. That design rule includes PyScript applications. 4) Use a timer or similar to call a function that reads the sensor and updates the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pyscript.write('id',value)
```

Or

```
Element('id').element.value=value
```